# A review was added TO, IN, or ON?

Tags: word-usage

I am getting confused after a few discussions with fellow colleagues, regarding the structure of the following sentence.

> A new **review** was added on **Sam's Bowling alley**.

My confusion is whether it should be **on**, **to**, or **in**. A *review* is added to/or/in a place (coffee place, library, museum, etc)

I'm finding it a little hard to find sentences with similar structure on the web.

PS: First question here, so unsure of tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Among the three alternatives you present*:

Unless the review is actually to be found **in** the establishment itself, or is an addition **to** the amenities offered there, what is being spoken of is a new account of the establishment which has been added in the latest edition of a publication which offers such reviews: a review **on** the bowling alley, meaning 'concerning' it  or 'about' it.

*But*:

Although a *review **on*** is not entirely unidiomatic—we speak for instance of an essay or paper **on** a topic—it will sound somewhat odd in most contexts. Prepositions like *on* and *to* are used to express the ‘objects’ of nouns derived from verbs expressing directed activity: *an attack **on** a position*, *a journey **to** a destination*. When the object has no such directional semantics we employ *of*: *the creation* or *our presentation* or *his review **of*** a work.

But things get a little trickier in your context. We don't much like separating *of* phrases from their heads:

> <sup>?</sup>A new review was added *of* Sam's bowling alley.

This would sound much better as

> A new review of Sam's bowling alley was added.

But this is ambiguous: it might be read as a review superseding an *old* review of Sam's bowling alley. To avoid that reading, you may mark the *of* phrase as a supplement or afterthought with commas. A supplemental *of* phrase is acceptable in either position:

> A new review, of Sam's bowling alley, was added.
>   A new review was added, of Sam's bowling alley.

Comment: I've never seen a review *on* a bowling alley. Do you mean a review *of* a bowling alley?

Comment: @JonStory I agree that *of* or *about* would be far more likely prepositions here, but *on* at least makes sense.  *In* and *to* would have a connotation of physical position.  Though it isn't used for reviews (in my experience) at least *on* can have the sort of meaning that n00bprogrammer asked about.  "She wrote a book report on Harry Potter." for instance.  I'm not really arguing with your point, just trying to expand it to verbs other than review.

Comment: On makes sense in theory, in practice, it wouldn't ever be used as such. A book report and a bowling alley review aren't equivalent, despite report/review being similar. Also note that a review/report would be a noun in this scenario, not a verb. You may review something, but in this context a review is a "thing".

Comment: @JonStory Good point, I meant *words* other than review.

Comment: @JonStory I agree; but I took OP's question to restrict the choices to those three alternatives. I will revise to express our preference for other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'add' a review to the thing that the review is about. It must be added to something.
Examples:

> *A new review about Sam's Bowling Alley was added to their website.*
>   *A new review was added to Sam's Bowling Alley Facebook page.*

*n.b.* Whilst the second example is ok, it doesn't exactly tell the reader whom the review is about.

As a stand alone sentence it could be written;

> *A new review was written about Sam's Bowling Alley.*

If you wrote:

> *A new review was written on Sam's Bowling Alley.*

It could be understood to mean that someone has scrawled a *(disparaging)* review on a wall of the bowling alley.

Comment: I like your answer, although there's nothing wrong with using "on" to mean "about" - as in, _"I read a review on the new_ Hunger Games _movie,"_ or, _"George wrote a review on the new Lorde album."_ Usually, people will understand the latter means a review _about_ the album, rather than thinking George used a Sharpie to write a review on a CD. And, of course, that's a legitimate use of _on_ ([Meaning #12 in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on)), so there's no need to use _about_ instead of _on_.

Comment: @J.R. Please do not edit my answers. If you think there is a mistake, kindly leave a comment and I will look into it.

Comment: Joe, I will fix errors when I see them. [That is the Stack Exchange way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120576/why-can-any-user-edit-any-other-users-question-or-answer), and I'm not about to try to keep track of who gets fixes, and who gets comments. If you don't like my edit, you'll be notified, and you'll have a chance to tweak it, as you did here. Also, where did you get the idea that _face-book_ [sic] was hyphenated? [You may want to rethink that one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook).

Comment: @J.R. Errors based on whose version of English? Who asked you to keep track of anything? Regardless of it being the SE way, I simply find it discourteous to be editing other's work willy-nilly. By all means do as you see fit; as must I. Thanks for the heads-up regarding Facebook, I had no idea it was all one word.

Comment: I think that the folks like @J.R. that have the ability to edit without requiring any additional approvals are very careful to only correct errors and not change the author's intent, i.e. they don't do it willy-nilly. Regardless, as JR mentioned, you can roll back any edit on your own content. I personally see it as someone doing me a favor when they correct a typo or clean up some formatting because it keeps folks focused on the content of what I wrote instead of the errors.

Comment: Joe, did you read the link I provided? _The Stack Exchange network encourages community-based edits. It is good etiquette not to roll back an edit that actually improved a post – this would be considered rude. If you don't like the idea of having your posts edited for clarity, spelling, etc., this site might not be the place for you._ Your commas were not correct in the original version of your post. I fixed them, the way the system was designed. When you asked me to "not edit" your answers, you were asking me to treat you differently than the rest of ELL – which I what I meant by "tracked."

Comment: @Colleen - Good point. I'd much rather someone quietly fix a typo or a misspelling in one of my answers than draw attention to it in a comment.